# Magento: bundle item selected products view front end to separate box

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle-product

I want to display all simple products of a bundle product without any select option (all simple products within the bundle product are required, hence the shop customer should not be able to choose between items in the bundle but s/he has to take all items within).

Can anyone direct me in how to accomplish this - or is there any extension available that would provide this functionality. Thanks.

---

*Current and expected result in frontend:*

[image]

*I think a backend structure like this would be neat:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most intuitive approach would be to simple utilize the functionality Magento provides already.

So, in order to achieve a structure as given in your screenshot you can create multiple sections - each of them holding exactly one `Simple Product`:

[image: bundle items split up in multiple sections]

The result (namely, each item is displayed without any select/input possibility for the shop customer (besides the quantity, if you wish)) in the frontend then would look like this:

[image: bundle item with split up sections in frontend]

Only drawback might be that you got different headlines between each option (unless you but some effort on the template, CSS or block - whatever suits you best).

---

In addition - firstly just to had it mentioned at this point as well and secondly since this basically depends on what you'd like to achieve with this setup - you may want to thing about utilizing `Grouped Products`.

The output in frontend would look like this:

[image: grouped product demo view]

**But** before going for one or the other you must understand that these two product types are completely different in the way they are working, hence also what they are used for differs a lot:

1. While a `Bundle Product` will be added to the cart "as is" - meaning, as a one position, inheriting all items specified - a `Grouped Product` would just be used for displaying the `Simple Product` together in the detail view but in cart again you will have them separated (hence the "group" could be overruled by the shop customer by just deleting an item from cart)
2. A `Grouped Product`, other than a `Bundle Product`, and basically for the above mentioned reason dose not provide any `required` selection even in the detail view (you may specify a default quantity by this still can be overruled by the shop customer at any time)

Not knowing your requirement you will have to choose on your own based on whether it is just about a design aspect or an actual sales-based decision to display product as per your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, But it's not worked for me, I try it but it every product separate as bundle item. I looking like https://colemanfurniture.com/north-shore-sleigh-bedroom-set.htm

Comment: I found extension But there is no backend demo https://www.wizkunde.nl/configurable-bundle.html

Comment: You should get in touch with the vendor for a backend demo then. These references would have been nice in the initial question though as your description didn't really hold any of these advanced use cases.